# Using gspread to clear two coumns on google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Running this following code removes all the values found in column L.

```
range_of_cells = worksheet.range('L:L')

for cell in range_of_cells:



    cell.value = ''



worksheet.update_cells(range_of_cells)
```

How would I modify this code so that it clears another column, Column D. So I would be removing all the values on Column L and Column D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to clear the multiple columns of the Spreadsheet using gspread for python.

In this case, how about using the batchUpdate method as follows?

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.
clearColumns = [4, 12]  # These column numbers mean columns "D" and "L"
client = gspread.authorize(creds) # Please use your authorization script.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
reqs = [{
    "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
            "sheetId": worksheet.id,
            "startColumnIndex": c - 1,
            "endColumnIndex": c
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredValue"
    }
} for c in clearColumns]
res = spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": reqs})
```

- When this script is run, the cell contents of columns "D" and "L" are cleared.
- In this script, one API call is used for clearing the multiple columns.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)